# Is it possible to import .dat files to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded unicenta oPOS database from sourceforge.net. Downloaded folder is having seg0 folder which contains .dat files. Is it possible to import those .dat files to MySQL DB? If yes. How?

Comment: As the [`sample_database_derby_3.50.txt`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unicentaopos/files/database/sample_database_derby_3.50.txt) file explains, the [`unicentaopos-database.zip`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unicentaopos/files/database/unicentaopos-database.zip) archive contains a sample Apache Derby Embedded database. The `.dat` files it contains are binary and cannot be imported in MySQL.

Comment: Yes you are right!! How can I integrate embedded database to project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Loader

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table
```

Offical Doc Link : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Only if `data.txt` is a CSV file or similar.

Comment: I have 454 files of .dat type

Comment: @axiac - You can also use FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'.It is not need to be files in .txt format

Comment: @msingh - I think you should develop small program. Logic: pick one by one query and execute above query

Comment: @KevalPithva, what about my_table? I don't have any tables in DB

Comment: Have you checked the `.dat` files specified in the question? They are binary files. They cannot be loaded by `LOAD DATA INFILE` no matter what parameters you use.

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE doesn't support for .dat files. In dat files data will be separated by length(suppose 0-2 column1, 3-8 column2 ......). So LOAD DATA INFILE doesn't know how to pick it.

Comment: Yes. Not possible.. Other way is to read each line from .dat file, set data into some java object.. use batch insert to load data into db..